# android iFrame not scrolling: what are practices to include our "widget" on client's Web pages while maintaining mobile compatibility

Tags: android, iframe, mobile, scroll, embed

We develop a SAAS booking application.

As part of this service we offer clients a "widget" to embed in their existing Webpage that allows client's to book.

We have implemented this widget as a simple iframe which has been working great up until now. The iFrame seemed a great solution and works in desktop browsers, iOS devices and some android  phones, **but we are getting reports that on some android devices the iFrame is not scrollable and causing users problems.**

We would like to be as compatible across devices as we can so we started thinking, are we doing this the right way...

**My question is, is an iFrame an appropriate way to include a widget like this into another site? Or, is there a better method to achieve the same result.**

My research shows that Youtube, Facebook etc seem to use iFrames to achieve this sort of functionality.

Maybe iFrames are the best way to do this and those users on older android devices will just have to accept a less than perfect experience, or maybe there is a better method for us to approach this.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Here is the iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://salontastic.salonmonster.com/client/index.php?layout=2" width="100%" min-width="630px" style="min-height:600px;" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate it in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/6htuz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't agree... I'm a developer too and I'm having tons of problem with iFrames on Android... At the moment, I'm testing with a Toshiba Folio 100 with the Android 2.2.5 stock browser and scrolling on iFrames does not work.
I tried that jsfiddle and I can't scroll it too!
Do anyone has a solution to this problem? I've spent days googling and trying a thousand of different tricks with no luck on the stock browser and Dolphin HD. In Opera Mobile and Firefox mobile they work just out of the box, but I need to guarantee full Android support even with the stock browser :-(

Comment: Thanks for that feedback lucaferrario.  That isn't good to hear that iframes aren't scrolling on Android 2.2.5.  We really need to be able to guarantee android support too, so this is a definite concern for us!

Comment: Well...on my site, I gave up supporting Android 2.2, because there are no way to scroll inside iFrames (and I've tried EVERYTHING, including some javascript libraries like iScroll)...
Instead, in Android >= 3.0 scrolling iFrames works just out of the box, without requiring any library. I haven't tested 2.3 Gingerbread yet...do you have any feedback on that?

Comment: [OFF TOPIC] The guys interested in this topic will certainly be interested also in this, to make the iFrame esperience in iOS better (it's only for iOS, it doesn't solve in any way the Android problem): [Native momentum scrolling in iOS 5](http://johanbrook.com/browsers/native-momentum-scrolling-ios-5/) [/OFF TOPIC]

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe's child page is 10,000 pixels tall (i.e. really really tall), and you want to embed it into a mobile web page such that all 10,000 pixels of content can be scrolled, then the solution is to make the iframe itself 10,000px tall:

The iframe's content won't scroll, but its containing window will.

Doesn't fix the scrolling issue exactly, but does allow for long iframe content to be scrolled through.